# Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing in response from request to MailChimp API URL

Tags: ajax, cors, mailchimp

I have Flask website and a simple form for MailChimp newsletter subscription. I am processing form with AJAX.

In order to do that I need to enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin so I am using Flask-CORS, but I keep getting same error:

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://us16.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/list-ID/members/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)**.

This is chunk of Python code responsible for that:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}}, send_wildcard=True)
```

Comment: It looks like you're using AJAX to call a URL at Mailchimp and this is not allowed by the Same Origin Policy - adding CORS to your Flask app won't help this situation. CORS would need to be activated/supported on the Mailchimp URL, which I don't think it is.

Comment: @MattHealy you are right. Thanks a lot! You saved me time trying to make it work. Post this as an answer so I can check it.

Comment: Thanks @Petar - have added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using AJAX to call a URL at Mailchimp and this is not allowed by the Same Origin Policy - adding CORS to your Flask app won't help this situation. CORS would need to be activated/supported on the Mailchimp URL, which I don't think it is.